# How to access and modify the same blocks of memory using multiple pthreads with or without mutex?

Tags: arrays, c, pthreads, mutex

So I have an array `unsigned char words[64000][9]`, filled with zeros. I have created two pthreads, one which will randomly select a row on the array and flip the last bit of the row to a 1 and the other thread should read the same 2D array and detect which one of the rows have a 1s. I have created the threads and I am passing in the same array like so -

```
pthread_create(&flip, NULL, flip_bit, (void*) (words));
pthread_create(&detect, NULL, detect_bit, (void*) (words));
```

Now my question is:
How do I make sure that two of the threads access this and modifies (doing what they do) the SAME 2D array? Is it possible to do it without mutex lock? If mutex lock is a must, how do I implement it for my case?

Thanks, I really appreciate it.

Comment: One thread modify the array and another just read from array ?

Comment: `How do .... the SAME 2D array?` I do not understand - you access the same array in both threads. Why is that an issue? `Is it possible to do it without mutex lock?` It is, in specific cases. What for? `If mutex lock is a must, how do I implement it for my case?` Still, a mutex is a tool you use _for_ something, not a tool you _have to_ use. I would advise instead of asking SO question, start by research and [reading books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073155/recommend-a-good-resource-for-approaches-to-concurrent-programming).

Comment: @FarhadSarvari Yes correct.

Comment: I don't understand what kind of issues are you experiencing. Are you obtaing unpredictable results? Can you describe them? Mutexes are for "regulating" the concurrent access to some specific resource, like your array. But what do the threads do? Depending on the answer you might rather need to synchronize them (for example: start detection after the flipping phase is completed). In other words: more code is required in order to make this question "answerable".